# Quantile regression model from `quantreg` does not finish computation

Tags: r, quantreg, quantile-regression

I am developing an iterative algorithm that uses quantile regression models at each iteration. For that I use the `rq` function from the `quantreg` package in R. So far it has worked fine. However, I have found a dataset where, at one of the iterations, the `rq` function simply gets stuck. No error message, no warning. It simply goes on as if still working, but never finishes computation.

I provide here a very small minimal code example. You can download the problematic data on this link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrlotit1ovk9yzd/r555.RData?dl=0

```
library(quantreg)
load('~r555.RData')

dependent = r$dependent
independent = r$independent

quantreg::rq(dependent ~ -1 + independent, tau=0.1)
```

If you execute the above mentioned code, the `rq` function will get stuck and never finish. Be aware that the data provided is part of the iterative process I am developing, so it has no direct interpretation by itself. I am writing to check for possible reasons on this behaviour and check for possible solutions.

Dont know if it matters, but I have tested this on two different computers running Windows10 and using different versions of the `quantreg` package.

Comment: Try raising the value of tau.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the default method="br" to method="fn" fixes the problem.
quantreg::rq(dependent ~ -1 + independent, tau=0.1, method="fn")